# Raw Carriage Return & New Line for Serial Port Write

Tags: c++, string, serial-port, carriage-return

I am new to C++, and I'm trying to generate a string "command\r\n". However, I need a raw carriage return & new line (see code bellow). I've tried R"(command\r\n)", but I don't think I have the right version to use raw strings. What are some alternative options (using Linux)?

Here is the code: I am trying to write to a serial port using a string command. The controller requires the \r\n.

```
//serial port write function

int write_only(int fd, string str) {
if (write(fd, str.c_str(), str.length()) == -1)
    {
        printf("write failed \n"); 
    }
}
// this call works 

write_only(fd, "command\r\n");
```

This call doesn't work but I need it so I can easily generate commands:

```
string buff = "command\r\n";
write_only(fd, buff);
```

Comment: Do you want to literally display "command\r\n"

Comment: Not display really. I convert the string to a character using str.c_str() and pass it to a write function.

Comment: I'm confused what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Nicole: If you're not displaying it, then what's the harm in creating it as "command\r\n"? If you need to have the "r" or the "n" show up, then escape the backslashes: "command\\r\\n"

Comment: It has to pass to a controller through a serial port write, and the controller requires a carriage return

Comment: I am also a little confused by the way this question is worded.  Maybe you're having problems with newline translations?  Make sure you have opened the serial port in binary mode, not text mode.

Comment: @Nicole: So why doesn't "command\r\n" work? I think you need to provide us a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or some kind of use case with actual, compiling code. It's really hard to help you based on what you've given us.

Comment: Carriage return is `\r`. Line feed is `\n`. Line terminator in most systems is `\r\n`; it is `\n` only in Unix, Linux, etc.

Comment: So in a raw string, the escaped characters are ignored, in C++11. So you're asking how to ignore the escaped characters in an older version of C++?

Comment: Yes I want to ignore the escape characters so that they are passed to the controller

Comment: So what on earth is your question exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Raw strings are mostly for situations when you *don't* want C escape sequences at all.  This is especially useful in cases where the `\` character is used with meaningful purposes inside the string itself, so you don't have to escape it at the programming language level.

For example, imagine the case of POSIX or C++11 regular expressions, which have many characters with special meanings, and also use `\` as the escape character to revert such characters back to their literal correspondents in the string to be matched.  Now imagine that you want to parse a Windows-styled UNC name, in the form `\\computer\share\pathname\filename`.  Compare the two possible ways of splitting those four components.

```
// With C-style strings: every "\" in the string to be parsed requires
// "\\" in regex level, and every "\" in regex level requires "\\" in
// language level.
regex unc_parser1("^\\\\\\\\([A-Za-z0-9._-]+)\\\\([^\\\\]+)\\\\((.*)\\\\)?([^\\\\]+)$");

// With raw strings: each desired "\" has to be escaped only in regex level.
regex unc_parser2(R"(^\\\\([A-Za-z0-9._-]+)\\([^\\]+)\\((.*)\\)?([^\\]+)$)");
```

(Of course, things can get a lot more complicated than this simple example...)

On the positive side, one possible solution to your problem is just to use simple compile-time string concatenation.  For example, all the strings below will have the same sequence of characters.

```
char s1[]="Line 1 has special char (\")\r\nLine 2: has special char (\\)\r\nLine 3 has no special chars\r\n";

#define CRLF "\r\n"

char s2[]=
    "Line 1 has special char (\")" CRLF
    "Line 2: has special char (\\)" CRLF
    "Line 3 has no special chars" CRLF
;

char s3[]=
    R"(Line 1 has special char ("))" CRLF
    R"(Line 2: has special char (\))" CRLF
    R"(Line 3 has no special chars)" CRLF
;
```

And to get raw strings to compile on Linux distros where C++11 isn't yet the default (all distros that I know of, BTW), you can just add `-std=c++11` to your `g++` or `clang++` command invocation.

Comment: Thanks. Changing from strings to character arrays worked.

Answer (score 1):

Seems a typo,change :

```
string buf = "command\r\n";
write_only(fd, buff);
```

to

```
string buf = "command\r\n";
write_only(fd, buf);
```

Comment: It wouldn't compile if this were the case.

Comment: @erip Agreed but did somebody say it did compile?

Comment: Yeah it doesn't complie

Comment: @Nicole This is good information to include in the question. Please post the error you received in your question as an edit.

Comment: The real code compiles. I mean that my post is just an example code. I didn't paste the entire main function - just the relevant call.